# Can we deduce that $h=f+g≠0$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let us consider three complex functions $f,g,h$. Let $A$ be a set such that $f≠0$ and $g≠0$ in $A$. Can we deduce that $h=f+g≠0$ in $A$. If not can we add some conditions $f,g$ such that the property holds true.

Comment: It's worse than you might think, without additional restrictions, because if $g=-f$ then $f+g$ is *identically* zero on $A$.

Comment: @MPW: I add this condition:  $g≠−f$

Comment: If there is a sequence $s_k\in A$ with an accumulation point, such that $f(x_k)=-g(x_k)$, then $h=0$ everywhere.

Comment: @ThomasRot: But I have assumed that $g≠−f$.

Comment: If you mean by $g\not=f$ that $g(x)\not=f(x)$ for each $x$, then I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: @Zeraoulia.E: The assumption "$g\neq f$" doesn't mean that $g(x)$ can never equal $f(x)$ (after all, that's what you want, so you can't just assume it!). Rather, it means that $g$ and $f$ are not *identically* equal; that is, it is not the case that $g(x) = f(x)$ for *all* $x$.

Comment: @MPW: Yes, your are absoluyely right. I add an answer to this question.

Comment: Your addition to the problem turned it into a triviality (you have taken as a given the very thing you are trying to show). It completely changed the meaning. You should **remove** "$g \neq -f$ in $A$" and replace it with something like "$g$ is not identically equal to $-f$ in $A$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, just given two nonzero functions $f,g$, we can't deduce that their sum $h=f+g$ is nonzero. For that we would also need the following condition to hold:

> For any $z$ in $A$, $f(z)\neq -g(z)$.

Now the proof is trivial: since for any $z$ in $A$, $f(z)\neq -g(z)$,  then $f(z)+g(z)\neq 0$.

Comment: This has no content. The OP misstated the condition "$g \neq -f$ in $A$". Your proof can be shortened to one line: "$f+g\neq 0$, and $h=f+g$, so $h\neq 0$". I can't believe it was accepted as the correct answer.

Comment: What else could possibly be the correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the condition is: $|g|<|f|$ so the sum $f+g$ cannot be zero (there is no intersection between the graphs of $f$ and $g$).

**Proof**: For all $s∈A$, we have $f(s)=u(s)+iv(s), g(s)=w(s)+iq(s)$, where $u,v,w,q:A→ℝ$. We have $$|g(s)|<|f(s)|⇒ √(u²+v²)-√(w²+d²)=(( (u-w)(u+w)+ (v-q)(v+q))/(√(u²+v²)+√(w²+d²)))<0$$

We remark that the conditions  $u=-w$ and  $v=-q$ cannot holds in the same time, so we must have $u≠-w$ or  $v≠-q$. So, $g(s)≠-f(s)$ for all $s∈A$, that is $h(s)≠0$ for all $s∈A$.

Comment: I agree, this condition is sufficient to guarantee the desired result.

Comment: @MPW: Does there is simpler conditions.

Comment: That seems pretty simple to me, but I doubt it's necessary. Any other condition I can think of seems to be a condition just on $h$. For example, I think it's enough to require that $\log(f+g)$ is continuously defined on $A$, provided that $A$ is simply connected. But that's probably equivalent to requiring that $f+g$ doesn't vanish on $A$ (again, this only works if $A$ is simply connected). Sorry, I don't know of a better condition.